# Is it "rude" to delete my own answer if it has a (physics)  discussion below it?

Tags: discussion

I`d just like to know what other people generally think about this ...

Comment: You can always flag it for diamomd mod attention stating 'comment cleanup please' or something in the other box. That way you don't have to delete it.

Comment: Ah, I'd assumed the question was about an answer that one would want to delete regardless of whether there are comments on it or not.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I think that's the correct interpretation. I misinterpreted it :\

Comment: @Manishearth It was not the discussion that embarasssed me (it`s quite fun when You are involved ;-) ) but rather my present inability to give further details about my answer when asked about in the comments ... So I had to retract it :-/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to delete your answer, I suppose it might be considered nice to wait until people stop posting comments... but really, you have no obligation to do so. If people want to have a discussion, they should be doing it on chat.

To sum up: officially, there is nothing wrong with doing what you're asking about.